# Cant update current row listview and my code is given below

Tags: android

Given below code in to update current row in `listview` but the list is not getting updated kindly tell me if any mistake in my code

```
private void update(int id)
    {

        int c = subaccountview.getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < c; i++)
        {
            View view = subaccountview.getChildAt(i);
        //  if (view.getTag() == id)
        //  {
                TextView someText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.balancenamenew);
                someText.setText(Sessiondata.getInstance().getRbalvalue());
                jsonCustomAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        //  }

                // update view
            }
        }
```

Comment: use Log.i(TAG, DESCRIPTIYN); After `notifyDataSetChanged` , Also Anfter comment `update view` two Brackets Closed!

Answer (score 1):

just change your line for notify to:

```
jsonCustomAdapter.notifyItemChanged(i) // i will be the position on which data is changed
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can delete the line `jsonCustomAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`. After you invoke setText() method on `TextView someText`, the content of the TextView has changed.

If any mistakes, please correct me.